# Bitbucket pull request detect too many diff compared to Sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I just want to know,

I created a `pull-request` from `branch-1` -> `branch-2`.
The bitbucket listed over `76` files changed.

But when I `merge` the `branch-1` -> `branch-2` using `SourceTree` it only detect `2` files.
Which is correct, since the changes I made was only there nothing more.

How could this be?

How can I align the Bitbucket with the correct one?

Thank you.

Comment: How long had it been since you last pulled the target branch in Sourcetree?

Comment: Hi @JimRedmond, it is always updated. Normally, I am pulling the changes on the target  branch first, then create a pr.

Comment: `Which is correct` which ever one reads the changes correctly... We can't know what the actual differences are/were. That is for you to investigate.